# Quitting during extended probation period

Tags: resignation, quitting, notice-period, probation

If I worked a 6 month probationary period and then it got extended for another 3 months and my original notice period during my first 6 months was 1 week, do I still only have to give 1 weeks notice in my extended 3 month period?

Comment: What does it say in your contract?

Comment: That's specified in a contract?   You are required to give a notice?

Comment: We cant say, check your contract.

Answer (score 1):

From the wordings you used ("extended probation"), it appears all the conditions from the probation period is applicable (that's what happens for *most* of the cases).

**However,** the best source of the information is your employment contract. In case there is no clear mention of the regulations in the contract regarding the "extended probation period", better to get in touch with your superior and/or, the HR team for clarification.